# SQL, extract everything before 5th comma

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

For example, my column "tags" have

```
"movie/spiderman,genre/action,movie:marvel", 
"movie/kingsman,genre/action",
"movie/spiderman,genre/action,movie:marvel,movie:dfjkl,movie:fskj,movie:aa,movie:mdkk"
```

I'm trying to return everything before 5th comma. below is the result example

```
"movie/spiderman,genre/action,movie:marvel", 
"movie/kingsman,genre/action",
"movie/spiderman,genre/action,movie:marvel,movie:dfjkl,movie:fskj"
```

I've tried below code but it's not working.

```
select
NVL(SUBSTRING(tags, 1,REGEXP_INSTR(tags,',',1,5) -1),tags)
from myTable
```

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, '^(([^,]*,){4}[^,]*).*', '\\1')`?

Comment: it worked!!! thank you!!!!!

Comment: I posted the answer below with explanations. It so unfortunate that non-capturing groups are not supported in POSIX regex flavor, although here it is not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```sql
REGEXP_REPLACE(tags, '^(([^,]*,){4}[^,]*).*', '\\1')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZjJRX/2).

The `REGEXP_REPLACE` will find the occurrence of the following pattern:

- `^` - start of string
- `(([^,]*,){4}[^,]*)` - Group 1 (`\1` refers to this part of the match): four sequences of any zero or more chars other than a comma and a comma, and then zero or more chars other than a comma
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

The `\1` replacement restores Group 1 value in the resulting string.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation as well!